# Speeding up apt-get install for many packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, speed, apt-get

I've noticed that much of the time taken by `apt-get install` when installing many packages / dependencies is due to many individual requests for packages / dependencies, even when the total download may not be large.

Is this the only way `apt-get install` operates or is there a way to send the same request for many packages to get a single tar-blob download?

**Edit**
To clarify, I am aware of the -y flags to make install non-interactive.
To be more specific, I am coming from the context of building images with Docker, where a Dockerfile change / cache invalidation results in packages being downloaded again.

An example is in the output below where there are many < 100kb packages being requested.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y arachni beef-xss ...

...
Get:76 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxcb-present0 amd64 1.12-1 [95.8 kB]
Get:77 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxcb-sync1 amd64 1.12-1 [99.2 kB]
Get:78 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxcb-xfixes0 amd64 1.12-1 [99.6 kB]
Get:79 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxshmfence1 amd64 1.2-1+b2 [7922 B]
Get:80 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libegl-mesa0 amd64 17.2.5-1 [120 kB]
Get:81 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libegl1 amd64 1.0.0-1 [33.0 kB]
Get:82 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libglapi-mesa amd64 17.2.5-1 [60.4 kB]
Get:83 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxcb-glx0 amd64 1.12-1 [113 kB]
Get:84 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxfixes3 amd64 1:5.0.3-1 [21.9 kB]
Get:85 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxdamage1 amd64 1:1.1.4-3 [14.4 kB]
Get:86 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libxxf86vm1 amd64 1:1.1.4-1+b2 [20.8 kB]
Get:87 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdrm-amdgpu1 amd64 2.4.89-1 [28.2 kB]
Get:88 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libpciaccess0 amd64 0.13.4-1+b2 [50.0 kB]
Get:89 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdrm-intel1 amd64 2.4.89-1 [69.3 kB]
Get:90 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdrm-nouveau2 amd64 2.4.89-1 [25.9 kB]
Get:91 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdrm-radeon1 amd64 2.4.89-1 [31.0 kB]
Get:92 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libelf1 amd64 0.170-0.2 [162 kB]
Get:93 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20170329-1 [85.2 kB]
Get:94 http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libllvm5.0 amd64 1:5.0.1-2 [13.7 MB]
...
```

Comment: *Is this the only way apt-get install operates or is there a way to send the same request for many packages to get a single tar-blob download?* **No, there isn't**.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `apt` requires confirmation from the user for many actions. These include setting dependencies and updating packages.

In order not to answer each time these requests, you can immediately specify your response by default, by specifying the `-y` flag:

```
sudo apt-get install -y package
```

As a result, all packages will be installed without additional questions to the administrator. You can also do this when upgrading the system:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-get.8.html

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up your apt operations by setting up either a dedicated repository mirror or a HTTP proxy. This way, you reduce the TCP round trip time  which speeds up overall operations.

Answer (score 0):

Use "apt-fast" ..it will download multiple packages simultaneously ..so it speeds things up. Go and find it..I don't think it will be hard to find.